# Parsing opening hours, discarding insane ones (part of the OpenStreetMap editor)

Tags: parsing, validation, kotlin

This code is used to check [opening hours data from OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours) can be handled by an editor app. In case where opening hours is not too complex data is also turned into an usable form.

It is a part of a [StreetComplete](https://github.com/westnordost/StreetComplete) editor app. This specific file will be part of pull request that will add ability to [resurvey opening hours](https://github.com/westnordost/StreetComplete/issues/1651).

Sadly, I had no good idea how to split this file into smaller one so it is quite large with 440 lines. Still, even smallest feedback about part of the code is welcomed - up to and including typos and grammar errors in comments.

For context - feature branch for this work, including all changes, is at https://github.com/westnordost/StreetComplete/compare/master...matkoniecz:resurvey

Feedback how to split this into smaller parts is also welcomed, but it seemed to me that any subset of this changes will be completely unclear.

`OpeningHoursTagParser.kt`:

```
package de.westnordost.streetcomplete.quests.opening_hours

import ch.poole.openinghoursparser.*
import de.westnordost.streetcomplete.quests.opening_hours.adapter.OpeningMonthsRow
import de.westnordost.streetcomplete.quests.opening_hours.adapter.OpeningWeekdaysRow
import de.westnordost.streetcomplete.quests.opening_hours.model.CircularSection
import de.westnordost.streetcomplete.quests.opening_hours.model.TimeRange
import de.westnordost.streetcomplete.quests.opening_hours.model.Weekdays
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

object OpeningHoursTagParser {
    // returns null for values that are invalid or not representable in
    // StreetComplete opening hours edit widget
    // otherwise returns data structure that can be directly used to
    // initialize this editing widget
    fun parse(openingHours: String): List<OpeningMonthsRow>? {
        val rules: ArrayList<Rule>
        try {
            val input = ByteArrayInputStream(openingHours.toByteArray())
            val parser = OpeningHoursParser(input)
            rules = parser.rules(false)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            // parsing failed, value is malformed
            return null
        }
        if (!isRulesetToStreetCompleteSupported(rules)) {
            // parsable, not handled by StreetComplete
            return null
        }
        return transformStreetCompleteCompatibleRulesetIntoInternalForm(rules)
    }

    private fun transformStreetCompleteCompatibleRulesetIntoInternalForm(rules: ArrayList<Rule>): List<OpeningMonthsRow>? {
        var data = mutableListOf(OpeningMonthsRow())
        for (rule in rules) {
            if (rule.dates != null) {
                // month based rules, so we need OpeningMonthsRow objects that will be created
                // and added later rather than a single catch-all row
                data = mutableListOf()
            }
        }

        for (rule in rules) {
            var index = 0
            val dates = rule.dates
            if (dates != null) {
                Assert.assert(dates.size == 1)
                val start = dates[0].startDate
                val end = dates[0].endDate ?: start
                index = getIndexOfOurMonthsRow(data, start.month.ordinal, end.month.ordinal)
                if (index == -1) {
                    // there is no reusable row matching out entry, we need to create a new one
                    data.add(OpeningMonthsRow(CircularSection(start.month.ordinal, end.month.ordinal)))
                    index = data.size - 1
                }
            }
            for (time in rule.times!!) {
                val dayData = daysWhenRuleApplies(rule)
                data[index].weekdaysList.add(OpeningWeekdaysRow(Weekdays(dayData), TimeRange(time.start, time.end)))
            }
        }

        return data
    }

    private fun getIndexOfOurMonthsRow(monthRows: List<OpeningMonthsRow>, startMonth: Int, endMonth: Int): Int {
        for ((index, row) in monthRows.withIndex()) {
            if (row.months.start == startMonth) {
                if (row.months.start == endMonth) {
                    return index
                }
            }
        }
        return -1
    }

    //returns array that can be used to initialize OpeningWeekdaysRow
    private fun daysWhenRuleApplies(rule: Rule): BooleanArray {
        val dayData = BooleanArray(8) { false }
        Assert.assert(rule.holidays != null || rule.days!!.size >= 0)
        val days = rule.days
        if (days != null) {
            Assert.assert(days.size == 1)
            val startDay = days[0].startDay
            val endDay = days[0].endDay
                    ?: startDay // endDay will be null for single day ranges
            if (startDay <= endDay) {
                // ranges like Tuesday-Saturday
                for (day in WeekDay.values()) {
                    if (day >= startDay) {
                        if (day <= endDay) {
                            dayData[day.ordinal] = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // ranges like Saturday-Tuesday
                for (day in WeekDay.values()) {
                    if (day <= endDay || day >= startDay) {
                        dayData[day.ordinal] = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val holidays = rule.holidays
        if (holidays != null) {
            Assert.assert(holidays.size == 1)
            Assert.assert(holidays[0].type == Holiday.Type.PH)
            Assert.assert(holidays[0].offset == 0)
            Assert.assert(holidays[0].useAsWeekDay)
            dayData[7] = true
        }
        return dayData
    }

    // Returns true iff supported by StreetComplete
    // Returns false otherwise, in cases where it is not directly representable
    //
    // It is first checking each rule (parts of opening_hours tag separated by ; sign)
    // is it possible to recreate it by taking only supported parts
    // later it checks also some additional limitations imposed by SC
    private fun isRulesetToStreetCompleteSupported(ruleset: ArrayList<Rule>): Boolean {
        for (rule in ruleset) {
            if (reduceRuleToStreetCompleteSupported(rule) == null) {
                return false
            }
        }
        if (includesMonthsRangeCrossingNewYearBoundary(ruleset)) {
            // strictly speaking this kind of ranges are supported, but not in an obvious way
            return false
        }
        if (areOnlySomeRulesMonthBased(ruleset)) {
            // StreetComplete can handle month based rules, but requires all of them to be month based
            return false
        }
        if (rulesAreOverridingOtherRules(ruleset)) {
            // this kind of opening hours specification likely require fix
            // anyway, it is not representable directly by SC
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun includesMonthsRangeCrossingNewYearBoundary(ruleset: ArrayList<Rule>): Boolean {
        for (rule in ruleset) {
            val dates = rule.dates
            if (dates != null) {
                Assert.assert(dates.size == 1)
                val endDate = dates[0].endDate
                if (endDate != null) {
                    if (dates[0].startDate.month > endDate.month) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun rulesAreOverridingOtherRules(ruleset: ArrayList<Rule>): Boolean {
        for (checkedRuleIndex in 0 until ruleset.size) {
            for (competingRuleIndex in 0 until ruleset.size) {
                if (checkedRuleIndex != competingRuleIndex) {
                    if (ruleset[checkedRuleIndex].dates != null) {
                        Assert.assert(ruleset[competingRuleIndex].dates != null)
                        val checkedRuleDate = ruleset[checkedRuleIndex].dates
                        val competingRuleDate = ruleset[competingRuleIndex].dates
                        Assert.assert(checkedRuleDate!!.size == 1)
                        Assert.assert(competingRuleDate!!.size == 1)
                        val firstDateRange = checkedRuleDate[0]
                        val secondDateRange = competingRuleDate[0]
                        if (areMonthRangesIntersecting(firstDateRange, secondDateRange)) {
                            return areDayRangesIntersecting(ruleset[checkedRuleIndex], ruleset[competingRuleIndex])
                        }
                    } else {
                        Assert.assert(ruleset[competingRuleIndex].dates == null)
                        return areDayRangesIntersecting(ruleset[checkedRuleIndex], ruleset[competingRuleIndex])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun areDayRangesIntersecting(ruleA: Rule, ruleB: Rule): Boolean {
        if (areHolidaysIntersecting(ruleA.holidays, ruleB.holidays)) {
            return true
        }
        val daysA = ruleA.days
        val daysB = ruleB.days
        if (daysA == null || daysB == null) {
            return false
        }
        Assert.assert(daysA.size == 1)
        Assert.assert(daysB.size == 1)
        val weekDayRangeA = daysA[0]
        val weekDayRangeB = daysB[0]
        val startA = weekDayRangeA.startDay
        val endA = weekDayRangeA.endDay ?: startA
        val startB = weekDayRangeB.startDay
        val endB = weekDayRangeB.endDay ?: startB
        val rangeA = CircularSection(startA.ordinal, endA.ordinal)
        val rangeB = CircularSection(startB.ordinal, endB.ordinal)
        return rangeA.intersects(rangeB)
    }

    private fun areHolidaysIntersecting(firstHolidays: MutableList<Holiday>?, secondHolidays: MutableList<Holiday>?): Boolean {
        if (firstHolidays == null || secondHolidays == null) {
            return false
        }
        for (holiday in firstHolidays) {
            for (holidayCompeting in secondHolidays) {
                Assert.assert(holiday.useAsWeekDay)
                Assert.assert(holidayCompeting.useAsWeekDay)
                Assert.assert(holiday.offset == 0)
                Assert.assert(holidayCompeting.offset == 0)
                if (holiday.type == holidayCompeting.type) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    // all info in dates, except months is ignored!
    private fun areMonthRangesIntersecting(aDateRange: DateRange?, bDateRange: DateRange?): Boolean {
        if (aDateRange == null || bDateRange == null) {
            return false
        }
        val startA = aDateRange.startDate
        val endA = aDateRange.endDate ?: aDateRange.startDate
        val startB = bDateRange.startDate
        val endB = bDateRange.endDate ?: bDateRange.startDate
        val rangeA = CircularSection(startA.month.ordinal, endA.month.ordinal)
        val rangeB = CircularSection(startB.month.ordinal, endB.month.ordinal)
        return rangeA.intersects(rangeB)
    }

    private fun areOnlySomeRulesMonthBased(ruleset: ArrayList<Rule>): Boolean {
        var rulesWithMonthLimits = 0
        for (rule in ruleset) {
            if (rule.dates != null) {
                rulesWithMonthLimits += 1
            }
        }
        if (rulesWithMonthLimits == 0) {
            return false
        }
        if (rulesWithMonthLimits == ruleset.size) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }


    // Reduces rule to a subset supported by StreetComplete
    // in case of any info that would be lost it returns null
    // null is also returned in cases where conversion would be necessary
    // and there is any risk of loss of any data
    private fun reduceRuleToStreetCompleteSupported(rule: Rule): Rule? { // following are ignored:
        val returned = emptyRule()
        val days = rule.days
        if (days == null && rule.holidays == null) {
            // SC requires explicit specification of days of a week or PH
            // holidays may contain some other holidays, but such cases will
            // fail a holiday-specific check
            return null
        }
        if (days != null) {
            val simplifiedWeekDayRanges: MutableList<WeekDayRange> = ArrayList()
            for (weekDayRange in days) {
                val simplifiedDateRange = reduceWeekDayRangeToSimpleDays(weekDayRange)
                        ?: return null
                simplifiedWeekDayRanges.add(simplifiedDateRange)
            }
            if (simplifiedWeekDayRanges.size > 1) {
                //TODO: support also Fr,Sa 11:00-00:00 kind of rules
                return null
            }
            returned.days = simplifiedWeekDayRanges // copy days of the week from the input rule
        }
        val dates = rule.dates
        if (dates != null) {
            val simplifiedDateRanges: MutableList<DateRange> = ArrayList()
            for (dateRange in dates) {
                val simplifiedDateRange = reduceDateRangeToFullMonths(dateRange) ?: return null
                simplifiedDateRanges.add(simplifiedDateRange)
            }
            if (simplifiedDateRanges.size > 1) {
                // happens with rules such as `Mo-Fr 7:30-18:00, Sa-Su 9:00-18:00`
                // that are intentionally rejected as are not directly representable in SC
                // and handling them may result in unexpected silent transformation
                // what is unwanted
                return null
            }
            returned.setDates(simplifiedDateRanges)
        }
        val times = rule.times
        if (times == null) {
            // explicit opening hours are required by SC
            return null
        } else {
            val simplifiedTimespans: ArrayList<TimeSpan> = ArrayList()
            for (time in times) {
                val simplifiedTimespan = reduceTimeRangeToSimpleTime(time) ?: return null
                simplifiedTimespans.add(simplifiedTimespan)
            }
            // multiple timespans may happen for rules such as "Mo-Su 09:00-12:00, 13:00-14:00"
            returned.times = simplifiedTimespans
        }
        val modifier = rule.modifier
        if (modifier != null) {
            val reducedModifier = reduceModifierToAcceptedBySC(modifier) ?: return null
            returned.modifier = reducedModifier
        }
        val holidays = rule.holidays
        if (holidays != null) {
            val reducedHolidays = reduceHolidaysToAcceptedBySC(holidays) ?: return null
            returned.holidays = reducedHolidays
        }
        return if (rule == returned) {
            // original rule is matching reduced rule as no special constructions were used
            returned
        } else {
            // not representable given our limitations
            null
        }
    }

    private fun reduceModifierToAcceptedBySC(modifier: RuleModifier): RuleModifier? {
        // public holidays with "off" specified explicitly are incompatible with SC due to
        // https://github.com/westnordost/StreetComplete/issues/276
        // other opening hours using "off" are rare and would require automated conversion
        // that would drop off part, what may cause issues in weird cases
        if (modifier.modifier != RuleModifier.Modifier.OPEN) {
            return null
        }
        return modifier
    }

    private fun reduceHolidaysToAcceptedBySC(holidays: List<Holiday>): List<Holiday>? {
        // PH, with set opening hours variant is supported by SC
        // many other variants are not, holidays list longer than 1 entry
        // indicates unsupported use
        if (holidays.size > 1) {
            return null
        }
        val holiday = holidays[0]
        val returned = Holiday()
        if (!holiday.useAsWeekDay) {
            // SC is not supporting "public holidays on Mondays" combinations
            return null
        }
        returned.useAsWeekDay = true
        if (holiday.type != Holiday.Type.PH) {
            // SC is not supporting SH
            return null
        }
        returned.type = Holiday.Type.PH
        return listOf(returned)
    }

    // StreetComplete is not supporting offsets, indexing by nth day of week etc
    // function may return identical or modified object or null
    // null or modified object indicates that original object was not representable in SC
    private fun reduceWeekDayRangeToSimpleDays(weekDayRange: WeekDayRange): WeekDayRange? {
        val returned = WeekDayRange()
        if (weekDayRange.startDay == null) {
            // invalid range
            return null
        }
        // returned.endDay may be null for range containing just a single day
        returned.endDay = weekDayRange.endDay
        returned.startDay = weekDayRange.startDay
        return returned
    }

    // StreetComplete supports solely date changing based on month
    // without any support for any other data ranges
    // function may return identical or modified object or null
    // null or modified object indicates that original object was not representable in SC
    private fun reduceDateRangeToFullMonths(dateRange: DateRange): DateRange? {
        for (date in arrayOf(dateRange.startDate, dateRange.endDate).filterNotNull()) {
            if (date.isOpenEnded) {
                return null //TODO: it may be supported by StreetComplete
            }
            if (date.weekDayOffset != null) {
                return null
            }
            if (date.dayOffset != 0) {
                return null
            }
        }
        val newDateRange = DateRange()

        val startDate = DateWithOffset()
        startDate.month = dateRange.startDate.month
        newDateRange.startDate = startDate

        val endDate = dateRange.endDate
        if (endDate != null) {
            // range with just single month will have endDate unset
            val newEndDate = DateWithOffset()
            newEndDate.month = endDate.month
            newDateRange.endDate = newEndDate
        }
        return newDateRange
    }

    // StreetComplete has no support for times like "from sunrise to sunset"
    // this function throws away any info over "from hour X to hour Y"
    // function may return identical or modified object or null
    // null or modified object indicates that original object was not representable in SC
    private fun reduceTimeRangeToSimpleTime(timeSpan: TimeSpan): TimeSpan? {
        val simplifiedTimespan = TimeSpan()
        if (timeSpan.startEvent != null) {
            return null
        }
        if (timeSpan.endEvent != null) {
            return null
        }
        val startInMinutesSinceMidnight = timeSpan.start
        if (startInMinutesSinceMidnight < 0) {
            return null
        }
        if (startInMinutesSinceMidnight > 24 * 60) {
            return null
        }
        simplifiedTimespan.start = startInMinutesSinceMidnight
        val endInMinutesSinceMidnight = timeSpan.end
        if (endInMinutesSinceMidnight < 0) {
            return null
        }
        simplifiedTimespan.end = endInMinutesSinceMidnight
        return simplifiedTimespan
    }

    private fun emptyRule(): Rule {
        // workaround needed to construct empty Rule object
        // proposal to allow creation of Rule objects is at
        // https://github.com/simonpoole/OpeningHoursParser/pull/24
        val input = ByteArrayInputStream("".toByteArray())
        val parser = OpeningHoursParser(input)
        try {
            val rules = parser.rules(true)
            return rules[0]
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw RuntimeException()
        }
    }

}
```

`WorkingAsssert.kt`

Story of this file is a bit embarrassing - I initially used `assert` and later discovered that it is not working. This probably should be eliminated before PR but I have no good idea for replacement and simply removing asserts seems to be a poor idea for me.

```
package de.westnordost.streetcomplete.quests.opening_hours

object Assert {
    fun assert(conditionAssertedToBeTrue: Boolean) {
        if(!conditionAssertedToBeTrue) {
            throw AssertionError()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note to self: I tried +100 bounty with "if you are unwilling to answer anyway - can you comment? I am unsure is it too long, boring or just there is nobody here who is familiar with Kotlin." comment, without triggering a reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Kotlin or how OpenStreetMap works so I'm probably the worst person to answer your question but since nobody has answered I'll give it a shot.

```
var data = mutableListOf(OpeningMonthsRow())
for (rule in rules) {
    if (rule.dates != null) {
        // month based rules, so we need OpeningMonthsRow objects that will be created
        // and added later rather than a single catch-all row
        data = mutableListOf()
    }
}
```

This code seems to be checking if the `dates` property on a `rule` is not null and if so set data to a new `mutableListOf()`. The `any()` operator could be used to simplify this comparison:

```
data = if (rules.any { it.rule != null }) mutableListOf() else mutableListOf(OpeningMonthsRow())
```

Which could make it easier to read.

```
private fun getIndexOfOurMonthsRow(monthRows: List<OpeningMonthsRow>, startMonth: Int, endMonth: Int): Int {
    for ((index, row) in monthRows.withIndex()) {
        if (row.months.start == startMonth) {
            if (row.months.start == endMonth) {
                return index
            }
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

This *might* be a potential bug; `row.months.start == startMonth` and `row.months.start == endMonth`; should the second be `row.months.end`? Additionally, `indexOfFirst` could be useful here (and use the predicate to match the object's properties.)

```
private fun isRulesetToStreetCompleteSupported(ruleset: ArrayList<Rule>): Boolean {
        for (rule in ruleset) {
            if (reduceRuleToStreetCompleteSupported(rule) == null) {
                return false
            }
        }
        if (includesMonthsRangeCrossingNewYearBoundary(ruleset)) {
            // strictly speaking this kind of ranges are supported, but not in an obvious way
            return false
        }
        if (areOnlySomeRulesMonthBased(ruleset)) {
            // StreetComplete can handle month based rules, but requires all of them to be month based
            return false
        }
        if (rulesAreOverridingOtherRules(ruleset)) {
            // this kind of opening hours specification likely require fix
            // anyway, it is not representable directly by SC
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

I would combine the `return false` seconds together, and collapse the loop. It could look like (and put comments on each statement):

```
private fun isRulesetToStreetCompleteSupported(ruleset: ArrayList<Rule>): Boolean {
    return if (ruleset.any { reduceRuleToStreetCompleteSupported(it) == null })
       || includesMonthsRangeCrossingNewYearBoundary(ruleset))
       || areOnlySomeRulesMonthBased(ruleset)
       || rulesAreOverridingOtherRules(ruleset));
}
```

For `rulesAreOverridingOtherRules`, it has a triple `for` loop which can make the logic difficult to follow. This problem can be generalized to finding any overlap between `n` or more intervals. This link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-two-integer-ranges-for-overlap gives some generic advice on how to approach such a problem.

I would then genericize the `*intersects` methods to have a single method which would check if there is an intersection on a generic date interval (or integer) and then create wrappers to convert the months/days/hours into that format.

For `emptyRule()`, I would remove the try block and just allow the `ParseException` to be thrown instead, as the stack trace information won't be thrown away.

There are a lot of null checks in the code; maybe the data can be cleaned or checked once and then re-converted into a different format where these checks are not required (e.g. making them a wrapper class that has methods to return object attributes conditionally.)

Comment: `row.months.start == startMonth and row.months.start == endMonth; should the second be row.months.end` Thanks! This alone was worth posting the question! And despite not knowing anything about OSM you know improved it by a tiny bit!